# Field Name for "positive, negative or neutral"

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, phrase-requests, hypernyms

I have a Web form which allows users to give feedback, as a hazard, incident, comment or suggestions.

I'm trying to work out what the best descriptive name for the "Feedback Type" would be, whose values are:

- positive
- negative
- neutral

Comment: The word is *type*. But typically it does not have a label at all, you just see the radio buttons "positive"/"neutral"/"negative" and it is perfectly self-explanatory.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because our Help Center says choosing names for things, including for software things, is out of our site scope.

Comment: @tchrist This has been basically closed for 4 years, why would you even bother with it? Besides just trying to farm points for more badges?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Polarity* in its broad sense is a good hypernym for *positive/ negative/ neutral.*

[ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/polarity):

> **1.2** The state of having two opposite or contradictory tendencies, opinions, or aspects.
>    *First is the duality obvious in all of Carter's work: polarity of opinion, …*

Though the "polarity" of an opinion can be positive or negative, neutral can also be a member of the group. (That's just my take, though.)

Answer (score 1):

**Sentiment** was the word I was looking for. I had to find a super-word for *positive* and *negative* and was eventually led to this question.

More specifically in my problem, I was dealing with text that was measured to have a level of *sentiment* which ranged on a scale from very *negative* to very *positive*. Therefore this word may not fit other things that can be positive or negative (such as physical entities like charge or vector direction).

Hope it can help someone after me.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatives to *Feedback type* include:

- Feedback Classification
- Feedback Kind
- Feedback Category

However, you could change the nature of the classification entirely and still receive essentially the same information:

- Positive --> Excellent
- Negative --> Needs improvement
- Neutral --> Fair

Then you could use wording like, "Feedback Grade."